# PHP: convert array with multiple arrays to one single associative array

Tags: php, arrays

My array `$rawArray` looks like this:

```
array ( 0 => array ( 'name' => 'firstname', 'value' => 'Max', ), 1 => array ( 'name' => 'lastname', 'value' => 'Smith ', ), 2 => array ( 'name' => 'age', 'value' => 12, ), 3 => array ( 'name' => 'gender', 'value' => 'male', ));
```

How can I convert this array in something like this?

```
$newArray = ['firstname' => 'Max', 'lastname' => 'Smith', 'age' => 12, 'gender' => 'male'];
```

So far I tried it with a foreach loop, but it didn't work:

```
$newArray = [];
foreach($rawArray as $key=>$value) {
   $newArray[$key] = [$value];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [array_column](http://php.net/array_column)

```
$arr = array ( 0 => array ( 'name' => 'firstname', 'value' => 'Max', ), 1 => array ( 'name' => 'lastname', 'value' => 'Smith ', ), 2 => array ( 'name' => 'age', 'value' => 12, ), 3 => array ( 'name' => 'gender', 'value' => 'male', ));

var_dump(array_column($arr, "value", "name"));
```

Result:

```
array(4) {
  ["firstname"]=>
  string(3) "Max"
  ["lastname"]=>
  string(6) "Smith "
  ["age"]=>
  int(12)
  ["gender"]=>
  string(4) "male"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($array as $value){
    $newArray[$value['name']] = $value['value'];
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($newArray);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [firstname] => Max
    [lastname] => Smith 
    [age] => 12
    [gender] => male
)
```